# Matlab error while creating csv file from image set using imread and csvwrite

Tags: matlab, syntax-error

I want to convert a set of images into a csv file. I was working with Matlab and I need each row corresponding to one image. I tried to do it with the following code

```
I=imread(c{n}); 

csvwrite('C:\Users\HP\Desktop\test.csv',I(:).','-append'); % c{n} contains the name of image files to be taken
```

but I am getting the following error

> Error using dlmwrite (line 112)
>    Invalid attribute tag: ,.
>
> Error in csvwrite (line 42)
>    `dlmwrite(filename, m, ',', r, c);`
>
> Error in Untitled (line 7)
>
> `csvwrite('C:\Users\HP\Desktop\test.csv',I(:).','-append');`

but if I try to do it without the '-append' there is no error.
How to change the code such that it takes all the images at once and produces a csv file with the single execution of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`csvwrite` is meant for writing comma separated values, so adding that `','` is wrong. Then you have put a dot('.') after `I(:)`, which is also wrong. I think you should better use `dlmwrite` if you want to append the files. It would go like `dlmwrite('C:\Users\HP\Desktop\test.csv',I(:)','-append')` (since you want each image as one row, you need to transpose the array).

For using this on all images, start by reading all the images into a cell array & then you use `cellfun(@(x) dlmwrite('C:\Users\HP\Desktop\test.csv',x(:)','-append'),a)`. Or for a much simpler version just run the lines in your code inside a `for` loop.